# UIToolbar not positioned at the bottom on device but appears ok in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode6, storyboard, uitoolbar

I'm testing the new universal storyboard in XCode 6. I basically created a view with a toolbar positioned at the bottom. When I run that basic example in the iPad the toolbar is not at the bottom

[image: iPad screenshot]

And here is in the storyboard

[image: xcode6 storyboard]

How can I place the UIToolbar at the bottom and using all the available width for all different screens?

Comment: @downvoter if you could kindly post a comment. I'll appreciate it. Downvote with no comment is not good for the community. Maybe I can improve my question if you point what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Autolayout.
Set the left margin, right margin and bottom space constraints on the toolbar to make it dock at the bottom. Optionally, add a height constraint if you want the toolbar height to be something other than the standard 44.

Your constraints on your toolbar in the storyboard should look like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM8gY.png): [image]

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I was looking for