# Wrong Toolbar position - iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, position, uitoolbar

I have a Collection View Controller inside a Navigation Controller with a Toolbar, the problem is that my Toolbar is floating. It looks like this:
[image: iPad screen]

And the Storyboard (I've added the Toolbar checking "Show Toolbar" in Navigation Controller Attributes Inspector):
[image: Xcode screen]

As you can see I have a Tab Bar Controller, then a Split View Controller, and in the Detail View Controller I have the Collection View Controller inside a Navigation Controller that I show programmatically.

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian

Comment: Your English is fine :)

Comment: You need to set constraint to bottom bar as below link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987104/uitoolbar-not-positioned-at-the-bottom-on-device-but-appears-ok-in-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method in your Detail View Controller

```
- (UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout {
    return UIRectEdgeAll;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your toolbar constraints might be incorrect or you maybe missing a constraint.

iOS is really picky and it's hard sometimes to get the constraints just right.

Comment: I can not set any Constraint for the Toolbar because it's integrated in Navigation Controller

Comment: What if you put it in View Controller and then added constraints?

Comment: How can I do this with Collection View Controller?

Comment: Do what? Add constraints?

Comment: Put Toolbar in a View Controller

Comment: So just drag and drop a toolbar into your View Controller from the Object library.

Comment: You can't do this with a Collection View Controller because it doesn't have a View at the top of hierarchy

Comment: Hmm, then I guess I'm at loss on how to fix this problem.